# Why does a click on a website zooms in on a part of the page?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, gmail

I'm not sure this is even a Mac issue, but when using Gmail on Chrome with OSX, clicking on certain parts of the page makes them zoom in.

It's a little hard to explain, so here's a vid:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_5BAXCWDEI

I'm clicking once on the new message popup for each zoom you see.

What's doing that?
How can I make it stop?

Is it even Mac related?

Comment: Have you checked the settings in System Preferences > Accessibility > Zoom?

Comment: Does this occur just with Gmail's text box? Does it occur if you maximise the compose 'window'?

Comment: @IconDaemon: didn't know about that, but zoom is off.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside: It does occur with the compose window maximized. I think I saw it happen in other places, but I can't find anything else. Maybe it's a Gmail/Chrome issue. I'll look.